How do I offset a border?
I'm wanting to recreate the image below.. (the screenshot is from Figma) I've been advised to use box shadows, borders offset etc..Any help would be massively appreciated :)
I've got the following code so far:


    .heading-decor {
      color: #192A51;
      background: #DCE8F8;
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-radius: 70px;
      box-shadow: 3px 3px 0px 2px red;
      padding: 10px;
      font-size: 26px;
      font-weight: 600;
      width: fit-content;
     }
<div class="heading-decor">Text goes in hereee</div>





Use a pseudo element for the border


.heading-decor {
  color: #192A51;
  background: #DCE8F8;
  border-radius: 80px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 600;
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.heading-decor:before {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  border-radius: inherit;
  pointer-events: none;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  translate: 5px -5px; /* adjust this */
} 
<div class="heading-decor">Text goes in hereee</div>



